# fabricjs objects order in group

Tags: javascript, html, canvas, fabricjs

I have no idea how to order objects in group other then repeat add and remove to sort the objects.

I tried `unshift` on group objects but it does not save state.

```
$(document).on("click", "#addToGroup", function() { 
var objects = canvas.getActiveObject();

    if(objects && objects.type === "activeSelection") {
      objects.toGroup();
      canvas.requestRenderAll();
    }   
});


count = 1;   

$(document).on("click", "#addObject", function() {
    canvas.add(new fabric.Rect({
      width: 100, height: 100, left: 100 + (count * 20), top: 20 + (count * 10), angle: -10,
      fill: 'rgba(0,200,0,1)'
    }));
});
```

[Template JSFiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/9vpqL7w0/1/)

Comment: http://fabricjs.com/docs/fabric.Group.html#insertAt

Comment: insertAt does not resolve the position and z-index of item

Comment: http://fabricjs.com/docs/fabric.Group.html#addWithUpdate

Comment: add with update push it to last, and the main point is to arrange the z-index of content

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can use [fabric.Object.prototype.moveTo()](http://fabricjs.com/docs/fabric.Object.html#moveTo). There is an undocumented behavior: if the object you call it upon is a part of a group, the object is moved within the group's `_objects` array, effectively changing its z-index when the group is redrawn.

Also, make sure to somehow force fabric to redraw the group after that, e.g. set `group.dirty = true`.

```js
const canvas = new fabric.Canvas("c")

const a = new fabric.Rect({
  width: 100,
  height: 100,
  left: 100,
  top: 20,
  angle: -10,
  fill: 'rgba(0,200,0,1)'
})
const b = new fabric.Rect({
  width: 50,
  height: 100,
  left: 150,
  top: 50,
  angle: 45,
  stroke: '#eee',
  strokeWidth: 10,
  fill: 'rgba(0,0,200,1)'
})
const c = new fabric.Circle({
  radius: 50,
  left: 150,
  top: 75,
  fill: '#aac'
})

const group = new fabric.Group([a, b, c])
canvas.add(group).requestRenderAll()

document.querySelector('#b1').addEventListener('click', () => {
  const bottomChild = group.getObjects()[0]
  bottomChild.moveTo(group.size() - 1)
  // force fabric to redraw the group
  group.dirty = true
  canvas.requestRenderAll()
})
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/fabric.js/2.4.6/fabric.js"></script>
<canvas id='c' width="400" height="200"></canvas>
<button id='b1'>move bottom to top</button>
```

Comment: nice, combine 'addWithUpdate' and 'moveTo' can do for ordering without removing.