# Arranging objects to front or back in fabric JS groups

Tags: javascript, fabricjs

I am using fabricJS to draw images on a canvas. In some cases, I have to add images from Base64 data urls as well to the canvas. The objects in the canvas are added to different groups. Now, I am able to add objects to the group as required, but if I need to send an object in the group to the back, I cannot find a way to do it.  I have found

```
fabricCanvas.sendToBack(objectToSendToBack);
```

works as expected, and sends the specified object to the back which is drawn directly on the canvas, but the same things with groups like:

```
fabricGroup.sendToBack(objectToSendToBack);
```

does not work and gives an error:

`Uncaught TypeError: Cannot read property 'sendToBack' of undefined` at `fabric.2.4.3.min.js:1`

I also tried, splicing the `fabricGroup._objects` array and adding `objectToSendToBack` at position `0`. But that stops rendering the image all together.

I have not been able to find any way to do it. Please provide some help.. Thanks in advance..

Comment: Where do you define or set _fabricGroup_? The error given clearly identifies _fabricGroup_ hasn't been declared.

Comment: @Dez.. Added it right after the line `fabricGroup.addWithUpdate(objectToSendToBack);`, there was no error on that line!

Comment: do `objectToSendToBack.sendToBack()`

Comment: Possible duplicate of [fabricjs objects order in group](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/54093149/fabricjs-objects-order-in-group)

Comment: Thanks millions.. Just what I needed.. Could you please add this as an answer? :)

Comment: @DebopamParua Mark as duplicate, what I have included.